# what is the best way to align and space Material Design Lite text input fields?

Tags: html, css, layout, material-design, flexbox

I have some Material Design Lite 1.0.6 input fields in a form. The fields are placed on the same line within a grid cell with a submit button on the right. The button currently has problems in Firefox because of a known problem with alignment.. it's ok in Safari/Chrome:

```
<form className="frontpage">
  <div className="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input className="mdl-textfield__input" id="email" type="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleEmailChange}/>
    <label className="mdl-textfield__label" htmlFor="email">email...</label>
    <span className="mdl-textfield__error">Input is not an email address!</span>
  </div>

  <div className="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input className="mdl-textfield__input" id="password" type="password" pattern="[A-Z,a-z,0-9\?@\$%&\*\-_=+!  ~\.,\/\\]*" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleEmailChange}/>
    <label className="mdl-textfield__label" htmlFor="password">password...</label>
    <span className="mdl-textfield__error">Input can only contain letters, numbers, and some special characters!</span>
  </div>

  <button className="mdl-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored mdl-js-ripple-effect" type="submit" name="login" disabled>Login</button>
</form>
```

I do see markup like:

```
<div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
```

in some examples but it doesn't seem to help with spacing the fields or buttons horizontally. I suspect I may be looking for a way to tell flexbox how to do it, but haven't found clear instructions on how to do this and i'm not sure whether this is the best mechanism. Controlling the spacing between grid cells would also be of interest.. perhaps also done with flexbox. I am using React to render the components, but i suspect this is specific to material-design lite.

thanks!

Comment: I was able to get separation between the fields/buttons by placing a <div className="content-grid mdl-grid">...</div> around the form contents then adding "mdl-cell" to the divs containing the individual fields/buttons. It seems reasonable in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Overwrite css 'display: block' to 'display: inline-block' in className ="mdl-textfield__input"

Comment: thanks for your answer, Mamun. Regrettably I am not using Material Design currently so I can't verify your answer properly and I don't want to mislead people. If someone can help to confirm your answer i'll accept it.